# How to recursively include only markdown in a directory in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am putting the general project documentations together with some project source files and rendering that to `gh-pages` with Jekyll. For security reasons and building time optimization, I want to exclude everything inside my source directory except markdown files in Jekyll configuration.

I tried this in the `_config.yml`:

```
exclude:
 - "src/*"
include:
 - "src/**.md
```

but it doesn't seem to find the nested markdown. I wonder how should this properly get done.

Comment: have you tried `- "src/**/*.md`?

Comment: @pme that's a good idea. Let me try that!